# Inserting Javascript Fragment Using Thymeleaf Includes Double Quotes

Tags: spring, google-visualization, thymeleaf

I am attempting to dynamically create Javascript within a Thymeleaf template in order to use Google Chart's Timeline package (note - this package isn't available in the Spring version of Google's library).

I have a Thymeleaf fragment ganttchartvalue.html with the following code, which is then included into the actual page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Card' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([ /*[[${Parms}]]*/ ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

In my GanttController class, I have the following code:

String Parms = "[ 'MegaCorp App 1', new Date(2018, 7, 2), new Date(2019, 4, 9) ]";
model.put("Parms", Parms);

(model is of type Map).

This is close to working, but the output that is generated (final page source) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Card' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([ "[ 'MegaCorp App 1', new Date(2018, 7, 2), new Date(2019, 4, 9) ]"]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Question:

How do I eliminate the additional double quotes (") before and after the inserted text in the dataTable.addRows method call so that this code works correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf isn't designed to be used that way.  You shouldn't be adding a JSON string to your model.  What you should be doing instead is adding java objects that will output the same way.  In your case:

```
model.put("parms", new Object[] {new String[] {"MegaCorp App 1", "2018-07-02", "2018-04-09"}});
```

And then in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
.
.
.
var rows = /*[[${parms}]]*/ null;
rows[0][1] = new Date(rows[0][1]);
rows[0][2] = new Date(rows[0][2]);
dataTable.addRows(rows);
.
.
.
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Metroids! This works correctly.  One minor edit - the order of the dates in the parms needs to be reversed if you are using the timeline object, because otherwise the package objects that the end date is before the start date.